# How to handle gesture recognizers on nested UITableViews?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a table that contains cells that have one nested table inside (comments-replies scenario).

The parent table view has two gesture recognizers (tap and long press) attached to it. The same applies to each of the child table views inside of it. I'm assigning both gesture recognizers to the entire tables rather than to each cell, and then using `location` to determine which cell triggered the gesture. The main table view gets handled from the controller, and each of the cells handle its own table view.

I've noticed sometimes gesture recognizers "clash", meaning I long press on a cell belonging to one of the child tables and the gesture recognizer from the parent table view gets called.

Is there a recommended way to prevent this from happening?

Here's a diagram of my current layout for completeness:

```
 Main UITableView with 2 gesture recognizers
|------------------------------------|
|                                    |
| Cell #1 on main table              |
|                                    |
| Nested UITableView inside cell #1  |
| with 2 gesture recognizers         |
| ---------------------------------- |
| | Cell #1 on nested table        | |
| |--------------------------------| |
| | Cell #2 on nested table        | |
| |--------------------------------| |
| | Cell #3 on nested table        | |
| |--------------------------------| |
|                                    |
|------------------------------------|
|                                    |
| Cell #2 on main table              |
|                                    |
| Nested UITableView inside cell #2  |
| with 2 gesture recognizers         |
| ---------------------------------- |
| | Cell #1 on nested table        | |
| |--------------------------------| |
| | Cell #2 on nested table        | |
| |--------------------------------| |
| | Cell #3 on nested table        | |
| |--------------------------------| |
|                                    |
|------------------------------------|
```

Thanks!